# How to handle/allow empty string as null for List<T>? properties in ASP.NET Core ModelState validation?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, modelstate

The ASP.NET Core 3.0 (with `Nullability References` enabled) API controller consumes the following model:

```
public class SampleModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; } = null!;

    public List<Guid>? Guids { get; set; }
}
```

For some reason, the client sends an empty string for the `Guids` property if the list should be empty. This marks the `ModelState` as `invalid` (saying that an empty string is not a valid value).

How to allow empty strings and convert them to set either an empty list or a `null` value to the `Guids` property (I don't care, choose whichever is easier)?

Comment: If you have any control over the client side, you should fix the problem there: it doesn't make any sense to send an empty string to represent a collection. If not, then you should probably change your model to represent what you actually expect the client to send you (e.g. a string for the Guids property?), and then do manual translation server-side.

Comment: Even if you *don't* have control over the client-side, it's *still* the client's responsibility to fix it on their side. An API is *literally* an interface. The consumer is responsible for implementing it correctly. You can't and shouldn't cater to mistakes clients make in that regard.

Comment: You are right. The issue was somewhere else.